# Is a surjective mapping of R2 to itself with full rank derivative everywhere necessarily injective?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

If $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R^2$ has rank 2 derivative everywhere, then by the inverse function theorem it is locally injective. If it is surjective, is it then necessarily globally injective as well?

What if we consider the same case, but for a map of $\mathbb R^{2+}$ to itself (i.e. ($x\geq 0,y\geq 0$)?

Answer (score 8):

No, $f$ needn't be globally injective. A counterexample is $$f:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C:z\mapsto \int_0^ze^{t^2}dt$$

**Why is that entire  map $f$ surjective?**
 Because by [Picard's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem) it could at most skip one value $b\in \mathbb C$ i.e. $f(\mathbb C)=\mathbb C\setminus \{b\}$.
  Of course that potential $b$ is nonzero since  $f(0)=0$.
But since $f(-z)=-f(z)$, if it skipped $b$ it would also skip $-b$ so that actually $b$ does not exist and $f$ is indeed surjective.
**Why is that entire  map $f$ not injective ?**
Because it would then be bijective and the only holomorphic bijections $u:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ are of the form $u(z)=az+b$ and have constant derivative $u'(z)=a$.
However $f'(z)=e^{z^2}$ is not constant.
**Why does $f$ have maximal real rank  everywhere?**
Because $f'(z)=e^{z^2}$ never vanishes.

**Nota Bene**
I have used that $\mathbb C$ is just $\mathbb R^2$, endowed with its well-known supplementary complex structure.

Comment: This is a lovely example! Where does it come from?

Comment: Dear @Mike: if I remember correctly it comes  from (some modification of?) an exercise in Dieudonné's  *Foundations of Modern Analysis* which I didn't understand at the time but reconstructed much later, when I became familiar with étale maps in complex geometry.

Comment: +1, very nice! It might be worth to note that if one looks for holomorphic functions $f$ that are local diffeomorphisms then the condition $f'(z) \neq 0$ implies that $f'(z)$ can be written as $f'(z) = e^{g(z)}$ for some entire function $g(z)$ and then one only needs to choose $g(z)$ to guarantee that $f$ is also onto but not one-to-one. Your choice for $g$ is the simplest one possible.

Comment: Thank you very much @levap: that's a very interesting observation.